# How to configure Joomla 1.7 SMTP email with a google apps email address

Tags: joomla, smtp, joomla1.7

I have a fresh Joomla 1.7 install.

I have a valid, confirmed, working google apps email that I can log into via the web client.
I have pop and imap enabled.

Configuration within Joomla Global Configuration Tab in the Mail Settings section is as follows:

```
Mailer: SMTP
From Email: [-me-]@decherney.com
From Name: Test Site Email
Sendmail Path: /usr/sbin/sendmail
SMTP Authentication: Yes
SMTP Security: SSL
SMTP Port: 465
SMTP Username: [-me-]@dechereny.com
SMTP Password: [-password-]
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
```

Anytime the site tries to send email whether for registration, mail, or other notification services it reports the following:

SMTP Error! Could not connect to SMTP host.

I have tried using port 587, using phpmail with the smtp host as ssl:smtp.gmail.com:465, and pretty much every other solution proposed on the net.

If anyone has a suggestion/answer I would be much appreciative.

Comment: allow access to less secure in gmail.
click here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out all I had to do was add the following line to the php.ini file

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

(or uncomment it)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the SendMail Path to : smtp.gmail.com

Everything else looks good.

Comment: gave this a shot but it still says "SMTP Error! Could not connect to SMTP host."