# Successfully mailing joomla contact form stopped mailing, now giving SMTP error

Tags: authentication, joomla, smtp

using joomla 1.7.2 & google app mailing which is working fine in the web client.

the contact form was sending mails successfully until 23 july, now it stopped mailng & giving the error

> "SMTP Error! Could not authenticate".

when using TLS its gives error:

> "SMTP Error! Could not authenticate. 
>   Language string failed to load:
>   tls Language string failed to load: smtp_errorSTARTTLS command used
>   when not advertised"

Here is the joomla Mail Setting in the global configuration that was working earlier:

```
Mailer                 SMTP
From email             email@mydomain.com
From Name              email@mydomain.com
Sendmail Path          /usr/sbin/sendmail
SMTP Authentication    Yes
SMTP Security          TLS
SMTP Port              587
SMTP Username          email@mydomain.com
SMTP Password          ******
SMTP Host              smtp.gmail.com
```

everything is same as it was when the mailing was working.

Now tried changing

```
smtp ports to: 465 & 587, with both SSL & TLS; 
smtp host to: ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, SMTP Security: None, SMTP Port: 25
```

Same mailing problem occurred few months back also but then just by using SMTP TLS/587 & full email id in the 'From Name' started the mailing.

BUT NOW NO SETTING SEEMS TO BE WORKING.

i also checked this post 
[How to configure Joomla 1.7 SMTP email with a google apps email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600390/how-to-configure-joomla-1-7-smtp-email-with-a-google-apps-email-address)
and found openssl is enabled in my php_info.

Did google changed anything or my hosting server? What should i look for if my hosing server changed anything?

i could not find any other setting to try!
Anyone plz provide some clue!

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution to the issue & mailing started again.
What's needed is to update the TXT DNS record to include the SPF entry for Google Mail.

so i updated my TXT DNS record to:

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:<my_domain_ip> +include:_spf.google.com ?all"
```

> #### So to be able to send emails using Google App Mailing from our domain we must have a TXT DNS record with atleast
>
> "v=spf1 +include:_spf.google.com ~all"`